# How to handle serializations and deserialization of all emuns in globally a project rather than putting custom converter attribute on all emun props

Tags: json, enums, converters

How to handle serializations and deserialization of all emuns in a project rather than putting custom converter attribute on all emun propperties

Suppose there 3 different types of enums in a project and want to handle serializations and deserialization of all emuns globally

I tried putting custom json converter of enums but as no of enus gets increased looking for a way to handle serializations and deserialization of all emuns globally

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.